# facing while executing the following python comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Need to know why I am getting this error when I use continue statement with else in python comprehension.

```py
sample_list = [6, 98, 34, 45, 64, 7, 2, 5, 78, 90, 324, 111, 657, 438]

# write code here 
s ={i:j if i%j == 0 else continue for i in sample_list for j in range(1,i+1)}
print(s)
```

while running the above comprehension in python I am getting this error

```
File "<ipython-input-14-0ca1dfa0b6f9>", line 4
    s ={i:j if i%j == 0 else continue for i in sample_list for j in range(1,i+1)}
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can't use statements like `continue` inside comprehensions, only expressions. Use an if-filter instead

Answer (score 0):

It worked by replacing `continue` with `print()` as suggested by @rdas

```
sample_list = [6, 98, 34, 45, 64, 7, 2, 5, 78, 90, 324, 111, 657, 438]
s ={i:j if i%j == 0 else print() for i in sample_list for j in range(1,i+1)}

print(s)
```

Comment: That's an ugly solution with a side effect. You just have to move the `if` to the right place: `s ={i:j for i in sample_list for j in range(1,i+1) if i%j == 0}`

Comment: I assume this is a reduced example because the result could be reached easier with `s = dict(zip(sample_list, sample_list))` or `s = {x:x for x in sample_list}`.